# Is firing off events from a RactiveJS components a common pattern?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

http://examples.ractivejs.org/comments

There is a line in the above example:

```
// fire an event, so we can (for example)
// save the comment to our server
this.fire( 'newComment', comment );
```

I'm curious if this is a common practice in Ractive? Firing the event rather than shooting of an AJAX request in the component? Or instantiating some model object and calling a #save method on that object to fire off the request?

Is this separation of concerns? Testing? Just simplified example code?

```
var user = new Comment({ text: "text is here", author: "author name" });
user.save()
```

The only thing I can think of is that by firing the event off and letting something else handle it would possibly make testing simpler? It helps with separation of concerns, but it also seems to me like it would make it more difficult to track down who is actually handling the actual creation of the data?

In your opinions, who would handle the firing of the event? In the example it looks like you just tack it on to the "root" ractive instance and let it handle it up there? That seems like it would get really full in a real world application?

Also, as a side question to his one, how often do you find yourself using "models" with ractive on a real world application? Coming from the server-side world, I'm pretty used to thinking of things in terms of classes and domain models. However, the only "model" library I've seen to be popular on front-end side of things is Backbone. However, Backbone seems to be a little overkill for what I'm thinking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious if this is a common practice in Ractive? Firing the event rather than shooting of an AJAX request in the component? Or instantiating some model object and calling a #save method on that object to fire off the request?

Let's say your app needs an `<input>` element to call an endpoint via AJAX when someone types in something. It's not the `<input>` that calls the AJAX. It's the surrounding code that hooks on to some known event fired by the input that does the AJAX when the event is fired. Ractive components are given the facilities needed to operate in that way, but you're not necessarily required to do so.

> how often do you find yourself using "models" with ractive on a real world application?

Ractive doesn't impose a convention. That's why the authors prefer to call it a library than a framework. You can use any programming pattern you think is necessary. I have used Ractive in the same way React components operate (one-way binding), and I know people who use Ractive merely as a templating engine. What you're provided is a set of API to be able to do stuff. It's up to you how you use it.

If you want to know if Ractive's the only one doing this, that's a no. Several other frameworks do components in one form or another: Ember, Angular (directives), React (Flux + stateless components), Riot, Polymer (web components).